# Angular observable returning object Object

Tags: angular

Probably a straight forward answer to this but I've been racking my brain whilst following a tutorial on http observables. I have the following data format returned from an endpoint:

```
{"result": [{"component": "UYT-3211"},{"component": "UYT-2121"}]}
```

I've created a component model and i pull the data back using search service:

```
  results: Component[];

  search(component: string): Observable<Component[]> {
  let apiURL = `${this.apiRoot}?component=${component}`;
  return this.http.get(apiURL)
      .map(res => {
        return res.json().result.map(item => {
          console.log(item);
          return new Component();
      });
    });
  }
```

and a search component

```
  doSearch(component :string) {
   this.searchService.search(component).subscribe( data => {
     this.results = data 
   });
 }
```

The output of console.log(item) is what i expect to see, json of each component, but when i print out this.results i get object Object.. I was expecting an array of components so i could just do `<div  *ngFor="let component of results">  </div>` can any one shed some light on what am i doing wrong? Appreciated.

Comment: In your `.map`, you're replacing each item of the array with `new Component()`. Is that intentional? Also, if you could create a Stackblitz that reproduces the issue, that would be great.

Comment: *when i print out this.results*: where and how do you do that? How is results initialized? Post all the relevant code, and the exact and complete output. Also, you shouldn't use the deprecated Http service anymore. It's been replaced by a much better HttpClient since 4.3.